# how to hide errorbox validation in java script

Tags: javascript, html

This code below is working but I want some modification in this code.

When user is not filling the box it is displaying error box that part is working but after filling it should disappear. So please anyone help me to solve the issue.

I have post the code here including html and java script so just copy and run it it will work and try to resolve my issue.

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  function validate()
          {

  var fname = document.form.Name.value;
  var lname = document.form.Lame.value;
  var same  = document.form.Same.value;

  if( fname == "" )
   {
     document.form.Name.focus() ;
     document.getElementById("errorBox1").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
     return false;
   }

   if( lname == "" )
   {
     document.form.Lame.focus() ;
     document.getElementById("errorBox2").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
     return false;
   }

  if( same == "" )

   {
     document.form.Same.focus() ;
     document.getElementById("errorBox3").innerHTML = "enter the Same name";
     return false;
   }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
     <body>
 <form name="form" >


 SSS :<input type="text" name="Name" value=""  class="input_name" ><div    id="errorBox1"> </div>
  <br> 
   SSmjhjk :<input type="text" name="Lame" value=""  class="input_name" ><div id = "errorBox2"></div>
  <br> 

 nngb :<input type="text" name="Same" value=""  class="input_name" ><div id = "errorBox3"></div>


    <input type=button  onClick="validate()" value=check> 

         </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , this might work for you

```
function validate() {
    var fname = document.form.Name.value;
    var lname = document.form.Lame.value;
    var same = document.form.Same.value;
    if (fname == "") {
        document.form.Name.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox1").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("errorBox1").innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (lname == "") {
        document.form.Lame.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox2").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("errorBox2").innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (same == ""){
        document.form.Same.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox3").innerHTML = "enter the Same name";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("errorBox3").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

use input type like this

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="validate()">
```

This will help you

Comment: its not working its same only .... i want when you enter the text and moving to next box then error message should disappear without clicking to submit button

Comment: onkeyup="validate()"> i am unable to use this because after entering one letter cursor automatically going to next box... so please suggest me something better thanks bro for your help please help here..

Comment: @sourav78611 remove all three focus() lines then try it will surely works

Comment: this line   document.form.Name.focus();  rite?

Answer (score 2):

In my first notice, You have the syntax error in your script. In your last condition you have written the code like `if else if( same == "" )`. This is wrong.

If you want check and display error for all the textbox at the same time, then you need to remove the return property from the script. Update your script like below.

```
function validate()
{
 var fname = document.form.Name.value;
 var lname = document.form.Lame.value;
 var same  = document.form.Same.value;
 document.getElementById("errorBox1").innerHTML ="";
 document.getElementById("errorBox2").innerHTML ="";
 document.getElementById("errorBox3").innerHTML ="";
 if( fname == "" )
 {
      document.getElementById("errorBox1").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
 }

 if( lname == "" )
 {

 document.getElementById("errorBox2").innerHTML = "enter the last name";
 }

 if( same == "" )
 {

 document.getElementById("errorBox3").innerHTML = "enter the Same name";
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <form name="form" >


  SSS :<input type="text" name="Name" value="" class="input_name" onkeyup="validate();" /><div id="errorBox1"> </div>
     <br> 
     SSmjhjk :<input type="text" name="Lame" onkeyup="validate();" value=""  class="input_name" /><div id = "errorBox2"></div>
     <br> 
  nngb :<input type="text" name="Same" onkeyup="validate();" value=""  class="input_name" /><div id = "errorBox3"></div>

  <input type="button" onclick="validate();" value="check" /> 

     </form>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/87bxK/2)

Comment: see your code is working with some advancement for that thank you but my question is different it is after displaying error when you are entering values to respective box then that error message should get disappear before clicking to submit button... please help me out here

Comment: Updated my answer. check it out.

Comment: thank you so much its working ... can you suggest one more thing like it is showing single time all the fields i want like when we are moving one by one box like that is should display only for particular blank box not for all boxes.... you got my point?

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/87bxK/1/ are you looking something like this??

Comment: when i am putting cursor on first box it is displaying for remaining other two boxes even i have not touched those boxes that i dont want please suggest me ....

Comment: thank you so much bro you are helping much...but this thing only just now i have done but this also i dont want see when i am filling first box then it should not display anything on another box but when i am jumping from first box to third box then it should display  for second box like in this way for whole process so this is also close but not exact...

Comment: when we are jumping from first box to third then message should display for second box like this..

Comment: bro.. please will you reply..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55909/discussion-between-sourav78611-and-suresh-ponnukalai).

Comment: or one more way is there when we click submit button it should display error message to respective blank box and when i fill it should get display before clicking to submit button

Comment: bro i have already accepted and one more thing i am asking now validation is solved but when am clicking to button then it is not going to its respective servlet , previously it was going what is the problem can you suggest something...?

Comment: when i am giving input type is submit then it is not checking validation but when input type is button then it is not going to next page or servlet only checking the validation

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/87bxK/3/ check this. for time being i have given yahoo url for successful submit. Meantime, accept means accept the answer. click the tick mark.

Comment: bro you have given and i am checking on your given link its not going in your link itself..

Comment: in jsfiddle it will not go. if you put target="_blank" in the form property then you can see that.

Comment: bro its working... actually today you have done some changes var status and all i didnt see before now i checked it properly now it is working properly thanks :)

Comment: hi bro i need one more validation logic for this how to set field value that it should take in this way only... ? 00:00:00 means i want to enter  hr:mn:sc in that particular box ...can you try?

Comment: bro i have another question regarding java script please check it here is  link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446724/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-html-using-java-script-without-clicking-subm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript only, you can hide the error div:

```
document.getElementById("errorBox1").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: and what about this line?     document.getElementById("errorBox1").innerHTML = "enter the first name";  ..........? your are saying .style.display then how it will display message