# How to calculate date difference in html using java script without clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I am giving two dates manually in the form after that one more empty box is there date difference should get calculated in terms of days in third box dynamically using java script 
for me its working when i am clicking submit button and using submit button property but i want it should get calculated after entering second date into second box and it should display in third box here is my code....
please help me out here..

*Script*

```
   function dateDiff() {
    date1 = new Date();
    date2 = new Date();
    diff = new Date();
    date1temp = new Date(dateform.firstdate.value);
    date1.setTime(date1temp.getTime());
    date2temp = new Date(dateform.seconddate.value);
    date2.setTime(date2temp.getTime());
    diff.setTime(Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()));
    timediff = diff.getTime();
    days = Math.floor(timediff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    dateform.difference.value = days;
    return false;
   }
```

*html*

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="Enter leave starting date">Enter leave starting date
            <input type="text" name="firstdate" />
        </label>
        <label for="Enter leave ending date">Enter leave ending date
            <input type="text" name="seconddate" onkeyup="return dateDiff();" />
        </label>
       <label>
         Date Difference (in days):  <input type=text name=difference>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle of this?

Comment: So you just need a trigger when to calculate the date difference?

Comment: here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lahmf/byJKg/

Comment: yea when we are entering date in second field it should calculate day difference dynamically and should display in third input box this much i want...i am new to java script

Comment: As you told you have working script with submit button, can you create a jsfiddle with that?

Comment: i don't see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/byJKg/5/

Comment: bro i am unable to create fiddle but i can you give link wher i got the code check this http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/16912-calculate-difference-between-two-time-in-jsp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the code works...the only thing you need is to give the form the name you use in the script

```
<form name="dateform">
```

....i tested it on your fiddle, it works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/byJKg/5/
...tough you might want to check if the datediff is not NaN

```
if(!isNaN(days)){
   dateform.difference.value = days;
}
```

*[edit] ...i just saw it wasn't your fiddle....but the fiddle posted by Felix Lahmer, with your source code*